# Are the breaking changes of the Facebook Graph API handled by Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, facebook-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Facebook is giving us warnings on the developers portal that the Graph API (Facebook) our Azure AD B2C tenant is using has some breaking changes for the endpoints it uses. It feels to me that managing this is not within our span of control and it is solely handled by Azure AD B2C. Is that a good assumption?

[Edit]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szEen.png)

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the warning that your seeing? I can try to see what the issue is. It looks like this is a duplicate of the MSDN thread here as well : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/874e18a9-77a4-4665-bfe2-5a46e377dbb4/are-the-breaking-changes-of-the-facebook-graph-api-handled-by-azure-ad-b2c

Comment: I added the picture. The MSDN thread was started by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AAD B2C calls the /me endpoint which translates to /user-id.
We do not provide a version number in our calls, as per FB's reference doc, that means it will call the oldest supported version automatically.

The other 2 calls do not appear to be being made by AAD B2C, does your B2C policy pass through the Facebook IdP Token and call Facebook Graph API itself?